# Istio RequestAuthentication from Origin Only and Excluding Internals Services in the mesh

Tags: authentication, jwt, istio

My use case is that i would deploy Elasticseach + Kibana into the mesh and configure End-User outside of Kubernetes to access Elasticsearch API with JWT Authentication. While i was successful in configuring and applying that I found that my Kibana deployment to be failing. I know it has something to do with the RequestAuthentication + AuthorizationPolicy defined I get a RBAC: access denied error when I tried CURLing elasticsearch from my kibana’s istio-proxy sidecar.

Have I misconfigured something here? Is there the option of just enabling end-user JWT for client requests outside of kubernetes and disabling it for internal service to service communication?

Comment: 1.Could you add yamls with your RequestAuthentication and AuthorizationPolicy? 2.What is your istio version? 3.Elasticsearch and kibana are both in istio enabled namespace?

Comment: apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
 name: elk-api-server
 namespace: istio-auth
#  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch-master
    # matchLabels:
    #   istio: ingressgateway
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "testing@secure.istio.io"
    jwksUri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.5/security/tools/jwt/samples/jwks.json"

Comment: apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: elk-auth-policy
  namespace: istio-auth
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch-master
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        requestPrincipals: ["*"]

Comment: Istio 1.5.4   and elasticsearch + kibana in the same namespace based on the example from above istio-auth

Comment: I'm trying to work around to see if applying it at the istio ingress gateway level works around this shortcoming in the sense that it wouldn't RequestAuthentication from internal service.

Comment: Things looked promising until i had instituted AuthorizationPolicy to request JWT token to be passed, but the moment i put that in i started to get 502 Bad Gateway error back