# 502 Bad Gateway Error After Instituting AuthorizationPolicy from Istio Documentation

Tags: authorization, istio

i'm using Istio 1.5.4 and trying apply the example referenced here:

https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication

Everything works as expected until defining the AuthorizationPolicy - the moment i introduce that i would get a 502 Bad Gateway error regardless if i provide a valid JWT token or not.

On a secondary note, I'm able to get the AuthorizationPolicy to work properly if i update the example to be applied at my own service namespaced level.  Then RequestAuthentication + AuthorizationPolicy would work as expected, however, i would run into a different roadblock where now internal service would also require a valid jwt token.

[authentication/authorization internal service issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652808/istio-requestauthentication-from-origin-only-and-excluding-internals-services-in)

Comment: I've discovered that the 502 is a result of my loadbalancer health check failing due to the AuthorizationPolicy applied.  Adding a conditional header User-Agent against my healh check probe seems to do the trick, but then i get back the net effect where no token provided is still getting through.

Answer (score 1):

> I've discovered that the 502 is a result of my loadbalancer health check failing due to the AuthorizationPolicy applied. Adding a conditional header User-Agent against my healh check probe seems to do the trick, but then i get back the net effect where no token provided is still getting through

No token is getting through because that´s how you configured your AuthorizationPolicy, that´s how `source: requestPrincipals: ["*"]` works. Take a look at this [example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/request_authentication/#RequestAuthentication).

> RequestAuthentication defines what request authentication methods are supported by a workload. If will reject a request if the request contains invalid authentication information, based on the configured authentication rules. **A request that does not contain any authentication credentials will be accepted but will not have any authenticated identity.** To restrict access to authenticated requests only, this should be accompanied by an authorization rule. Examples:
>
> Require JWT for all request for workloads that have label app:httpbin

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "issuer-foo"
    jwksUri: https://example.com/.well-known/jwks.json
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpbin
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        requestPrincipals: ["*"]
```

**Use** `requestPrincipals: ["testing@secure.istio.io/testing@secure.istio.io"]` instead as mentioned [here](https://istiobyexample.dev/jwt/), then it will accept only requests with token.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
 name: frontend
 namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "testing@secure.istio.io"
    jwksUri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.5/security/tools/jwt/samples/jwks.json"
```

> The second resource is an AuthorizationPolicy, which ensures that all requests have a JWT - and rejects requests that do not, returning a 403 error.

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: require-jwt
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
       requestPrincipals: ["testing@secure.istio.io/testing@secure.istio.io"]
```

> Once we apply these resources, we can curl the Istio ingress gateway without a JWT, and see that the AuthorizationPolicy is rejecting our request because we did not supply a token:

```
$ curl ${INGRESS_IP}
RBAC: access denied
```

> Finally, if we curl with a valid JWT, we can successfully reach the frontend via the IngressGateway:

```
$ curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${VALID_JWT}" ${INGRESS_IP}
Hello World! /
```

Comment: jt, the problem with this example and approach is that all services inside the mesh that requires access to frontend would required JWT.

my use case is this. namespace = istio-test

service1 = elasticsearch

service2 = kibana

requirement - expose elasticsearch application REST API to external application requiring  JWT authentication. 

Authorize kibana access to elasticsearch without the use of JWT.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://discuss.istio.io/t/end-user-auth-for-external-use-and-mtls-for-internal-service-service-communication/3172/12) and [this](https://discuss.istio.io/t/authentication-policy-origins-jwt-internal-vs-public-access/4921) istio discuss post.

Comment: i tried the same approach and security is being ignored , what could be ? here is the repo  github.com/jamesmedice/Istio-Rbac-Policy-Mesh and security app  
         github.com/jamesmedice/Istio-Security-VS-Mesh